# How to access a user's logging info in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, logging, nslog

I've read about the [Unified Logging Framework](https://www.avanderlee.com/workflow/oslog-unified-logging/) as well as the new [iOS 14 API](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10168/) regarding logging on devices, but I can't find anything that would enable me to write a log on a user's device to troubleshoot an issue, and for me to be able to review it?  What is the current state of the art for doing this inside the Apple framework, or 3rd party library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have read *is* how to write a log on the user's device. When you use `os_log` or the new Logger, and you log with anything but the lowest level, it is written into the log. The user can extract it using the `log` command in the Terminal. Of course you need to give instructions, so practice on your own device first.

For instance, if I hook my phone, TheMattPhone, to the computer, and say in the Terminal

```
sudo log collect --device-name "TheMattPhone" --last 1h
```

...then the result is that my home directory now contains a file called *system_logs.logarchive*. The user can zip that up and send it to you.

There are much more sophisticated commands that can extract just your app's logs, or even particular logs, depending on how you've configured the logger.

Note that the log written to the file will be redacted unless you mark interpolated material as `public`.

Comment: I may have not phrased my question well.  I am a developer, how can I see a log my app writes on my user's device so that I can troubleshoot?  For example Xcode has the helpful Organizer with crash reports.  I am looking for something similar for logging?

Comment: No, what I'm describing won't arrive magically over the airwaves thru the Organizer. The user would have to send it to you (and then you can view it very nicely filtered in the Console app). It sounds to me like you're looking for some third-party framework.

Comment: See also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/acquiring_crash_reports_and_diagnostic_logs

Comment: Thanks matt, very helpful.  Is there any option to obtain the log if they don't have a mac?

Comment: I don’t think so. Look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/acquiring_crash_reports_and_diagnostic_logs The last section implies, if this is not a crash, the only way to fetch the logs is thru a Mac. And that’s with TestFlight which is dedicated to user testing.